# Angular 7 i18n support translate typescript file

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-i18n

Versions.

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.13.4",
"@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "0.13.4",
"@angular/animations": "7.2.2",
"@angular/cdk": "7.2.2",
"@angular/cli": "7.3.3",
"@angular/common": "7.2.6",
"@angular/compiler": "7.2.6",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "7.2.6",
"@angular/core": "7.2.6",
"@angular/forms": "7.2.6",
"@angular/language-service": "7.2.6",
"@angular/material": "7.2.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "7.2.6",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.2.6",
"@angular/router": "7.2.6",
```

This is a support request:
I started internationalizing my application, and I met the following problem: when generating the bundle for the Japanese locale (for example), with using i18n for .html file perfectly used but i can not using with .ts file. As far as I find out there are two ways, ngx-translate and @angular/localize.

Ngx-translate not suitable for my project, @angular/localize using start with angular 9 but i using angular 7.

Is there any way translate typescript file with angular 7 ? Or do I really have to upgrade to angular 9 to use @angular/localize

Comment: ngx-translate why is not suitable for you ?

Comment: I'm using xi18n with my project, building towards internationalization with environments.
Using ngx-translate I will have to rebuild the project from scratch, ngx-translate is suitable for converting multiple languages at a time

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately yes.

The versions of the angular packages proceed the same as the main repo. The oldest version of the [@angular/localize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/localize/v/9.1.13) package goes back to 9.1.13.

Comment: I think so too, I wanted to make sure I didn't miss any way to translate .ts file with angular 7 because upgrading the project to angular 9 is quite complicated